# Which MySQL data-type to store Tweets from Twitter

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I need to store a great amount of twitter tweets

- Which could be the best database type for tweets  → best guess is just as `TEXT`
- I need to prevent duplicates, too. → best guess `varchar(255)` with a `UNIQUE key`

  - May be `varchar(140)` character should work but we also have chinese ones? (would save a lot of Space)

Another idea is, to store all tweets as `TEXT` and add another column with the Tweets hashed to MD5 and add a `UNIQUE key` over the column.

Question:
What's the best MySQL type to store tweets?

Comment: Hash tweets to md5? why?

Comment: To the closers/downvoters, using the word "best" in the title does not by definition mean that the OP is asking for a subjective answer.  We're not looking for "the best database".  We're looking for the most suitable data type.  There's an enormous difference.

Comment: Does twitter store all tweets and does each tweet have an associated ID that you could use to retrieve the tweets via an api?

Comment: Hash tweets to md5? < i can add an primary or unique key to that column but not to a TEXT column

Comment: thank you Kirk Woll! corrected!

Comment: Why would you add a unique constraint?? If someone tweets Hello World! then I would not be able to re-tweet that! Unless i dont understand the requirements.

Comment: You will probably want to search by similarity on this table too (fulltext search), meaning you'd have to use MYISAM, or wait for 5.6.4 InnoDB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

Twitter no longer counts user handles, [among other things](http://www.wired.co.uk/article/twitter-character-limit), against the 140 character limit, so `varchar(140)` will not be sufficient to store the entirety of long tweets with user handles in them.

However, upon inspection, I'm still not able to go over 140 characters when mentioning another twitter user via their handle.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

`varchar(140)` in the `utf8` format.

`TEXT` would be horribly inefficient. `char(140)` would waste too much space.

Not that this supports my answer, but is [interesting reading](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/12/19/how-twitter-stores-250-million-tweets-a-day-using-mysql.html) nonetheless on technology and efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

Since a tweet is a defined as a 140-character string, you could store it as `nvarchar(140)` though calling that "the best" is a bit presumptuous because we have no idea what your intended use is....

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter

http://support.twitter.com/groups/31-twitter-basics/topics/109-tweets-messages/articles/127856-about-tweets-twitter-updates

There is no reason to do an MD5 hash. Just set a uniqueness constraint on the column if that is your actual intent.

Answer (score 2):

A tweet is max 140 chars, so I would use that for sure.

`varchar(140)` is what I would use.